# Android MapView animateTo and zoomIn in the same time(*with a twist)

Tags: java, android, android-mapview

How can I call animateTo and zoomIn for Map View Controller at the same time to the point witch is not visible now(For example I'm seeing capital of USA and then I'm seeing capital of Brazil)?